# jQuery update background color having no visual effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a single page web app in development where based on xml I render items on screen ( add and manipulate DOM elements)

As part of this I have code that fires to amend visual properties such as color, background, text size all of which works in 99% of cases. The screen has a hierarchy within the 'scriptForm' div in the page where 
scriptForm div

```
 - windows div with id #win__

 -- panels div with id #pnl__

 --- children from here
```

The background color affects everything from panels down and items don't inherit unless explicitly set to.

the windows however show rgb values in DOM explorer but the background remains white.

the code I use to manipulate the background is shown below with a9 representing the element id value;

```
var a9 = '#' + name;
    if (background.length === 7) {
        $(a9).css("background", background);
}
```

Can anyone suggest why I'm not able to see the effects correctly?

Comment: I have checked there is nothing in my JS or css that would conflict and found nothing

Comment: drop a !important next to the background variable , see if that changes the color, if not try a large z-index

Comment: Are you sure the selector is correct? Have you checked the applied styles in the console to see if it's being overridden, and if so, by what?

Comment: I've checked the console and can see that background-Color  values in Rab are showing but still appears white

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using:

```
$(a9).css("background-color", background);
```

instead of

```
$(a9).css("background", background);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 $(a9).css("background-color", background);
```

Also, you should not use inline styles. So better soution would be to assign a class instead like:

```
  $(a9).addClass("class_name");
```

And in your css file create class like(EX.) :

```
 .class_name{
    background-color: #ffffff;
 }
```

Comment: An "inline style" is like `<div style='background-color: black'>`

Comment: @JohnHascall : Yes, thats what  will be added in DOM by this code: $(a9).css("background-color", 'black');

Comment: Yes, and doing `$(a9).css("background-color", 'black');` is NOT an inline style.

Comment: John my preference normally would be to use classes but as I need to add background and foreground colours on the fly it isn't feasable or efficient